# Symfony 1.4 plugin task

Tags: plugins, symfony-1.4, task

I've just created my first symfony plug-in. It's a private plug-in (for now) and i have a task that i've added. For some reason the task isn't available on the symfony CLI interface. Even of if i enable the plugin in the ProjectConfigurator Class.

If i move the task to the symfony root lib/ folder, i can see it available in the symfony CLI. But when i move it to my plugin task folder: nothing.

I think i have the task in the correct spot? Is there something else that i'm missing?

here's my dir structure:

```
plugins/
    myFirstPlugin/
        config/
        data/
        lib/
            task/
                myFirstPluginTask.class.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Duh!  I didn't enable the plugin in the root/config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php. I enabled it in the app configuration.class.php with evidently won't work because it wasn't loaded in the ProjectConfiguration class to begin with.

I'm a Noob!

Thanks to me for answering my own question. ;)